# How to change Wordpress Password Reset Email?

Tags: wordpress

I want to change the default Password Reset Email in Wordpress 5.2.2

I have tried the following code but it is not working.

```
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_message', 'my_retrieve_password_message', 10, 4 );
function my_retrieve_password_message( $message, $key, $user_login, $user_data ) {

    // Start with the default content.
    $site_name = wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES );
    $message = __( '(UPDATED)Someone has requested a password reset for the following account:' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    /* translators: %s: site name */
    $message .= sprintf( __( 'Site Name: %s' ), $site_name ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    /* translators: %s: user login */
    $message .= sprintf( __( 'Username: %s' ), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __( 'If this was a mistake,  just ignore this email and nothing will happen.' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __( 'To reset your password, visit the following address:' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= '<' . network_site_url( "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode( $user_login ), 'login' ) . ">\r\n";

    // Return the filtered message.
    return $message;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This answer here is working well for me: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/262425

And here is how you can change the email it sends from and the subject.

```
// Function to change default wordpress@domain.com email address
function wp_sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
return 'YOUR_EMAIL_HERE';
}

// Function to change sender name
function wp_sender_name( $original_email_from ) {
return 'YOUR_SUBJECT_HERE';
}

// Add our functions to WordPress filters 
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'wp_sender_email' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'wp_sender_name' );
```